# Search file attachments module and drupal 9

Tags: 9

I have a website that uses the [search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) module to generate search results for sets of pages and for files - mostly pdfs. To help do this I use the [search_file_attachments](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_file_attachments) project.

In the process of upgrading this site to drupal 9, I have discovered this module has not been upgraded and it appears it may have been abandoned. The [issues page](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/search_file_attachments?text=Drupal%209&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All&order=search_api_relevance&sort=desc) list a number of drupal 9 issues to be resolved and an official notice that a new maintainer is required

Some initial snooping around with the upgrade_status project leads me to believe there's a fair few compatibility changes to make and I am not sure I have the skills for it.

Can anyone suggest a way forward for a search feature that needs to search both files and pages? Is there an alternative to this project for Drupal 9?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_attachments works well for me

Comment: Ah. I didn't realise that module has all the same functionality. thanks. I got confused by the name.